# Identify groups of rows in close proximity

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am doing a project for school and have been given a database over gps-recordings for three people during the course of a week. I am trying to group these recordings into trips based on the time between them. If a recording is within 300 seconds from the recording before it, they are considered to be part of the same trip, otherwise, they are considered part of different trips.

So far I have managed to calculate the time difference between a recording on row n and the one on row n-1 and I am now trying to create a function for merging the recordings intro trips. This would have been real easy in another programming language, but in this course we are using PostgreSQL which I am not that well versed in.

To solve this, I am trying to create a function with a variable that increases every time the time difference between two recordings is greater than 300 seconds and assigns each row to a trip based on the variable. This is as far as I have currently gotten, although at the moment, the variable resets X all the time, thus assigning all rows to trip 1...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tripmerge(time_diff double precision)
RETURNs integer AS $$
declare 
X integer := 1;
ID integer;
BEGIN
  IF time_diff < 300 THEN
    ID = X;
  ELSE 
    ID =X;
    X:=X+1;
  END IF;
 RETURN ID;
END;$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How do I change so `X` does not reset all the time? I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.

EDIT:

This is the table I am working with:

```
curr_rec (timestamp), prev_rec (timestamp), time_diff (double precision)
```

With this being a sample of the dataset:

```
'2013-11-14 05:22:33.991+01',null ,null
'2013-11-14 09:15:40.485+01','2013-11-14 05:22:33.991+01',13986.494
'2013-11-14 09:17:04.837+01','2013-11-14 09:15:40.485+01',84.352
'2013-11-14 09:17:43.055+01','2013-11-14 09:17:04.837+01',38.218
'2013-11-14 09:23:24.205+01','2013-11-14 09:17:43.055+01',341.15
```

The expected result would add a column:

```
tripID
1
2
2
2
3
```

And I think this fiddle should be working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4e3e5/1/0

Comment: `triplegs`? triplets? I have read the question twice and still have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Please add: Your version of Postgres, the table definition (`\d recordings` in psql), sample data and an example for result data - or better yet a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: I see what you meant and edited the text to try to clarify my question, thank you :)

Comment: Can probably be solved with a single query, [like this one.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389) But I still don't see a table definition or sample data or the expected result ...

Comment: As a general note, it sounds like you're trying to implement a procedural solution to your problem in a relational database. Using procedural solutions is generally not a good idea in a relational database. Rethink your problem. SQL is a **declarative** langauge; see if you can come up with a way of expressing what you need in SQL. I will also note that my experience is that you very rarely need to resort to procedural code in PostgreSQL; its features make finding declarative (pure SQL) solutions possible in a much wider variety of problems than other databases \*cough*Oracle*cough*.

Comment: Erwin: I added all the needed data and what I expect to get out of it as well as a fiddle. If it could be solved by a query that would be great, although the one you linked to is far to advanced for me to be able to interpret.

Comment: Note that you need to [use `@erwin` to send me a message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). I saw it by chance.

Comment: @jpmc26: My answer goes to demonstrate you were right on target with your comment. There are those cases where procedural elements come in handy. They are just not that common.

Comment: With all the information you added, you finally made it a good question. (+1) Remember to start with the big picture and the necessary context in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query uses only `curr_rec`, not the other redundant, precomputed columns:

```
SELECT 1 + count(step OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY curr_rec) AS trip_id
FROM  (
   SELECT curr_rec
         ,lag(curr_rec) OVER (ORDER BY curr_rec) AS prev_rec
         ,curr_rec - lag(curr_rec) OVER (ORDER BY curr_rec)
                                        > interval '5 min' AS step
   FROM  timestamps
   ) x;
```

Key features are:

- The [window function **`lag()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html), which I use to see if the previous row is more than 5 minutes ago. (Just using an `interval` for the comparison, no need to extract seconds)
- The window aggregate function **`count()`** - that's just the basic aggregate function with an `OVER` clause.
  The expression `step OR NULL` only leaves `TRUE` or `NULL`, where only `TRUE` is counted in a running count, thereby arriving at your desired result.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4e3e5/5) (building on the one you provided).